# How can I recover my Outlook VBA code after Outlook crashed and I had to reinstall Outlook?

Tags: vba, crash, outlook, recover

My Outlook crashed.  I made a full backup of my hard drive (from c:).  Is there anyway I can recover my Outlook VBA code from my backup?

Comment: There should be a **VbaProject.OTM** file in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook`, thats where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA code is stored in a file named VBAProject.otm

Search for the new empty VBAProject.otm file. Replace it with the backup version.

Some details here http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-backup-and-save-your-outlook-vba-macros/

Comment: I can't believe it.  Your answer was right on!!  Thank You! Thank You! Thank You!!!!! :-) :-) :-)  There was one weird thing I wanted to mention.  When I found my old VBAProject.otm, I saw that the file date was from back in 2013.  At first, I thought it couldn't be my file, so I continued to search with no luck.  Finally, I decided that 2013 was the best I could do, so I copied that file over the new one.  I couldn't believe my eyes when I opened VBA and saw all my recent code there.  Again, Thank You!!